# Can you identify these figurines?

Tags: statue

I'm looking to find info about these particular statues.
Any info would be great. Had these for years and really wondering who they are, where they're from and any history if known.
[image: statue 1]
[image: statue 2 a]
[image: statue 2 b]

Comment: The heavy metal looking sign is supposed to be the Karana mudra that's apparently for banishing and expelling negativity. It is supposed to express a very powerful energy that is able to expel negative energy & ward off evil. The superstitious who have this Buddha making the Karana mudra, are encouraged to try and be very mindful about its placement.  I wonder if Karuna and Karana are related.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I did think it was to ward off negative energy actually. It's been placed by the front entry way at my mother's place.

Answer (score 1):

They are all the Buddha as far as I can see.  The top one looks Balinese.  The metal casting look possible Indian,  I would guess 1950s or earlier.

Comment: They all look Buddha to me as well. I have not read about mudras in any sutta.

Answer (score 0):

These are Buddhas. I couldn’t find any mention of mudras in suttas. I [asked](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/49450/11541) about mudras in this forum but nobody found any mention of mudras in suttas.