# Has Buddha ever talked about Mudras?

Tags: mudra

I have seen images of Buddha in different mudras like karana mudra etc on the Internet. However I have not read about any mudras in suttas.

My question is : Is there any Sutta which talks about mudras to practice ?

Comment: maybe you should learn some mudras and when it occurs u might wonder to yourself no?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the most famous is the earth-touching mudra, a.k.a. "calling the earth to witness".

That's not in [Snp 3.2](https://suttacentral.net/snp3.2/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin) -- instead I think it's in the Introduction to the Jakata Tales and maybe a commentary on the Buddhavamsa.

It's difficult to prove that something doesn't exist -- i.e. that none of the Suttas talk about mudras -- but [Cunda Kammaraputta Sutta (AN 10.176)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an10/an10.176.than.html) may be relevant. It says that Brahmans have purification rites of which this is one ...

> Come, now, my good man: Get up at the proper time from your bed and touch the earth.

... and that instead of that, the Buddha teaches that one is made impure or pure by unskilful or by skillful bodily actions, verbal actions, and mental actions.